# AngularJS ng-if to determine which col-md to use

Tags: angularjs

I have a line like this:

```
<div class="col-md-6"  ng-if="user.cobuyer">
```

user.cobuyer is either true or false, if its false, I want the col-md-6 to be col-md-12, if its true it can be col-md-6

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ng-class` with a ternary for this, don't use `ng-if`.

```
<div ng-class="user.cobuyer ? 'col-md-6' : 'col-md-12">
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can just do something like:

```
<div ng-class="{col-md-6: user.cobuyer, col-md-12: !user.cobuyer}">
```